# Como deletar todos os registros de FK ao deletar o "dono" deles com o Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize-js

Estou fazendo um banco de dados e nele tem umas propriedades e tem os usuários.

Um usuário pode ter várias propriedades, então na tabela de propriedades eu inseri a coluna `user_id`, para referenciar o usuário.

Porém quando vou criar a tabela propriedades pelo sequelize-cli. A FK fica assim:

```
user_id: {
  type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
  references: { model:'users', key:'id'},
  onUpdate:'NO ACTION',
  onDelete:'NO ACTION',
  allowNull:false
}
```

O `onUpdate`, seria quando deletar uma propriedade, não fazer nada em usuários e a mesma coisa para `onDelete`. Porém ai que vem minha dúvida, eu queria que quando eu deletasse o usuário, também deletasse todas as propriedades que ele possui.

Como faço isso?

OBS: Admita propriedades como sendo imóveis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso (um para muitos - N:M) seria atribuir ao `onDelete` o valor `CASCADE`, onde agora, quando o usuario for removido, todas as propriedade (relacionadas ao usuario) tambem serao removidas.

```js
user_id: {
  type:Sequelize.INTEGER,
  references: { model:'users', key:'id'},
  onUpdate:'NO ACTION',
  onDelete:'CASCADE',
  allowNull:false
}
```

Lembrando que na [documentacao](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/associations/), o seu `onUpdate`, por padrão, também tem valor `CASCADE`,que indica que a ação referencial será executada quando um registro for modificado na tabela pai (tabela de usuário), então sugiro que altere o `onUpdate` para `CASCADE` também, a menos que você não ache necessario.